# Compiled Linq & String.Contains

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq-to-SQL and I use compiled Linq for better performance.

I have users table with a `INT` field called "LookingFor" that can have the following values: `1,2,3,12,123,13,23`.

I wrote a query to return the users based on the "lookingFor" column and I want to return all users that contain the "lookingFor" value (not only those equal to it).

In example if `user.LookingFor = 12` , and query paramter is `1`, and this user should be selected.

```
private static Func<NeDataContext, int, IQueryable<int>>
      MainSearchQuery = CompiledQuery.Compile((NeDataContext db, int lookingFor) =>
         (from u in db.Users
          where (lookingFor == -1 ? true : u.LookingFor.ToString().Contains(lookingFor)                         
    select u.username);
```

This WORKS on non complied linq but throws error when using compiled.
How do I fix it using compiled Linq?

I get this error:

**Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method.**

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: Also, compiled LinQ might be less beneficial than you might think, see: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/03/compiled-or-bust.html

Answer (score 8):

I'm facing the same problem. I have managed for now just one workaround for this problem. Instead of using

```
u.LookingFor.ToString().Contains(lookingFor)
```

I've used

```
u.LookingFor.ToString().IndexOf(lookingFor) >= 0
```

Comment: I'm using this solution, however in most cases you probably want >= 0, not > 0, in case it's at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You're performing operations on the lookingFor argument that cannot be translated to SQL. I'm actually surprised that this works when not compiling the query.

If it's possible, I suggest that you change your database to make this query easier. Create a table to store the LookingFor property for users. Or you can change the datatype of lookingFor to a string, which has less of an impact on the database design.

Comment: if i change the datatype to string , will this work in complied linq? i just dont see the reason why it should make a difference.