# Use contains in LINQ to SQL join

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, join

How can I do a LINQ to SQL join without an exact match? For example, say I have a table `form` with the data `John Smith (2)` and I want to join it to the field `Smith` in table `name`. Something like this

```
var query =
    from f in db.form
    join n in db.name
        on f.nameField like '%' + n.firstName + '%'
```

Although the `like` keyword doesn't seem to be available to me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't use `like` in a Linq join. In fact, you can't use `like` in Linq at all, only conventional string methods like `StartsWith`, `EndsWith`, or `Contains`.

You'd have to do something like this:

```
var query =
    from f in db.form
    from n in db.name.Where(x => f.nameField.Contains(x.firstName))
    ...
```

Comment: I don't know if it's some weird implementation error in my code or not, but this gave me an error: `Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method.` I got it to work using `IndexOf` instead of `Contains` as detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7574433/1080891)

Comment: @CavynVonDeylen Hmm, that seem to be a limitation of Linq-to-SQL. `string.Contains` is the standard mechanism in other ORM's.

Comment: @CavynVonDeylen you can try to do the following
`from n in db.name.ToList().Where(x => f.nameField.Contains(x.firstName))`. The `.ToList()` method evaluates the entity set and puts everything out of the database into memory. By doing this, you can use the `string.Contains()` method. Just be aware and do not evaluate all the objects in your table at once.

Comment: What does two `from`s mean? Does it equal a `join` statement?

Comment: @Hp93 It equates to a [`CROSS JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690.aspx), but note that the `Where` does limit the record set of `db.name` being considered.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, there is [a way of doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835790/how-to-do-sql-like-in-linq), but it's not as neat as using the standard linq stuff:

```
from c in dc.Organization
where SqlMethods.Like(c.Hierarchy, "%/12/%")
select *;
```

(borrowed from the user L P's answer in the linked question)

Comment: +1 Good point, this will work because OP is using Linq-to-SQL. In most other cases, this method will not translate.

Comment: @p.s.w.g true! should've mentioned that, this is strictly linq-to-sql.