# LINQ JOIN with different data types

Tags: linq

I have a situation where I am trying to do a join on 2 tables.

Table one has the following:

```
 User       ID
 john       1 
 mary       3
 tim        4
```

Table 2 has the following: (Note that ID in table 2 is comma delimited. Note that each ID in table 2 is unique. )

```
company         ID
 100           '150', '4', '9'   
 101           '102','2', '10'
```

as you can see in the first row of table 2 there is a match with user tim as they both have  4 in them so company 100 is associated.

Issue is with LINQ I am not sure how to do the join between these 2 tables.

Comment: To be clear, table 2 has a comma-delimited value list?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: Is this an existing system or something new? If new, why not go with an intermediate mapping table for this inherently many-to-many relationship?

Comment: This is an existing system. Each ID in table 2 is unique.

Comment: Your best bet may be to create a view that better normalizes the data in Table 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your companies table ids and format them into more readable list :

```
var companiesReadableList =
            companies.SelectMany(x => x.ID.Replace("'", "").Split(',').Select(y => new {ID = y.Trim(), company = x.company}));
```

all that's left is to join user table :

```
var joinedView = users.Join(companiesReadableList, user => user.ID.ToString(), company => company.ID,
            (user, company) => new {user.user, user.ID, company.company});
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

try something like using `like` clause with single quotations

```
var res = from Table1
join Table2 
on SqlMethods.Like(Table1.Id , '\'' + Table2.Id + '\'')
select ....
```

i can't test this but i based my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431154/use-contains-in-linq-to-sql-join)

should work if linq-to-sql