# LINQ can't use string.contains?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

This is my code:

```
string queryString = "Marco".ToLower();
utenti = db.User.Where(p => 
        queryString.Contains(p.Nickname.ToLower()) ||
            queryString.Contains(p.Nome.ToLower()) ||
            queryString.Contains(p.Cognome.ToLower())).ToList();
```

but I get:

> Only arguments that can be evaluated on the client are supported for the String.Contains method.

Why? Can't I use `.Contains()`?

Answer (score 44):

Try `.IndexOf`. It is not LINQ that can't do `Contains`, it's LINQ to Entities and LINQ to SQL that can't.

```
string queryString = "Marco";
utenti = db.User.Where(p => 
    queryString.IndexOf(p.Nickname, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
        queryString.IndexOf(p.Nome, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0 ||
        queryString.IndexOf(p.Cognom, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCasee) >= 0)
.ToList();
```

**Why?**

LINQ uses [deferred execution](https://www.google.com/search?q=linq%20deferred%20execution). This means it waits until you want to iterate over your query results before it does anything. There are 3 main types of LINQ:

1. LINQ to Objects - when your `IEnumerable` is already on the heap.
2. LINQ to Entities - when you want to query a database using Entity Framework.
3. LINQ to SQL - when you want to query a database using LINQ to SQL.

Deferred execution in the context of the second 2 means that your query is not executed on the database until you enumerate the results in a `foreach` block, or invoke an enumeration method like `.ToList`, `.ToArray`, etc. Until then, your query is just stored as expression trees in memory.

Your query would work just peachy if `db.User` was a collection in memory. However when the data is in a database, LINQ to Entities (or LINQ to SQL) must translate your expression trees to what it calls a "store expression" -- which is just fancy talk for "convert my LINQ expressions to SQL".

Now imagine you had a custom C# algorithm you wanted to use for your query, and you did something like this:

```
var result = db.User.Where(x => MyCustomMethod(x));
```

There is no way today that LINQ to Entities can convert your C# code into a SQL query (store expression). It is the same with a lot of other C# methods you rely on daily. It also does not support `.ToLower`, `.ToUpper`, `.StartsWith`, `.EndsWith`, etc. There is a limited number of C# methods that can be converted to store expressions, and `.IndexOf` just happens to be one of them.

However keep in mind that it is only the string object's `Contains` method that we are talking about here that is not supported for store expressions. LINQ to Entities does support `.Contains` on `IEnumerable`s. The following is valid and will work with LINQ to Entities (not sure about LINQ to SQL):

```
var idsIWantToFind = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var users = db.Where(x => idsIWantToFind.Contains(x.UserId));
```

The above is the equivalent of doing a SQL `WHERE UserId IN (1, 2, 3)` predicate.

Comment: To expand on this, and help maybe clarify the issue, the code inside the `Where` needs to be converted to real SQL. Not every function can do that. Therefore, you have a subset of things that can be converted (e.g. `IndexOf`) and then you also have the entity database extensions that can do some stuff like date comparisons and such.

Comment: To expand on @neoistheone's comment, think of trying to do something like `.Where(x => MyCustomMethod(x))`. The database does not know how to invoke that custom method in SQL. It's the same with other methods like `.StartsWith`, `.Contains`, etc. Some methods are supported when they can be translated to a store expresion (SQL), the rest are not.

Comment: I think we've got it all now. :D

Comment: I'd suggest you to add both these comments to answer as they are more worthy that what is in answer now(which makes people to understand why it won't work) :)

Comment: I've never faced any error while using `ToLower`, `ToUpper`, `StartsWith`, `EndsWith`, `Contains` (on string) in `linq to entities`... So either your explanation is valid for `linq to sql` (I've no experience with it) only, or this is another problem.

Comment: Maybe it is related to the database provider. I can confirm Contains and related methods of String work well with EF5 against SQL Server.